# Force to treat file like html

Tags: html

I am displaying programming files on a website as plain, raw text. Now I want to use syntax highlighting using html. It works great and looks good, the only problem is, that I have to create directory and index.html files for all the files.

Like Normally: `mysite.com/code.h` -->raw
With Syntax Highlightng: `mysite.com/code/code1.html`

My problem is, if I put the html as .h file, it displays all html as raw code.

Is there a way to force any, or many extensions to be displayed as html?

like: (test.txt)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Super Awesome Site</title>
<head>
<body>
true
</body>
</html>
```

If this is in the test.html file, it displays html, if its in test.txt file, it dispalys as raw code.
is there a way to enforce test.txt to be displayed as html?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but from what I can figure out, you should be doing this on the *server* not the HTML. For example, if you're using Apache, maybe `mod_rewrite` will help you.

Comment: You could achieve that in multiple ways, by configuring the webserver (e.g. [AddType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) for Apache), by setting the Content-Type with a server script (e.g. PHP), or on the client-side... What are your options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file called `.htaccess` in the same directory of your `test.html`:

`.htaccess`

If you want to parse PHP inside the `.txt`:

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .txt`

If you want to only show HTML inside the `.txt`:

`AddType text/html .txt`

Comment: Thanks! I only needed AddType application/x-httpd-php .txt in the .htaccess file. It worked :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the response header

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

before you send the page to the browser. It can be done using [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function if php is an option.

Answer (score 1):

Why won't you make 1 HTML file, which takes file name from query string and loads it into DIV as part of markup? Something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sorce code loader</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

$(function() {
    $('#container').load(getParameterByName('filename'));
})

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Call it with file name in `filename` parameter